# Matching data between multiple columns of 2 dataframes to return "matched" value or mean based on one or two matched columns

Tags: r

I have a complex problem and am not sure how to proceed.  I have two dataframes called `df1`:

```
structure(list(State = structure(1:2, .Label = c("Aaa", "Dd"), class = "factor"), 
City = structure(1:2, .Label = c("bb", "e"), class = "factor"), 
Type1 = c(NA, NA), Type2 = c(NA, NA)), .Names = c("State", 
"City", "Type1", "Type2"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))
```

and `df2`:

```
structure(list(state = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L
), .Label = c("Aaa", "Dd"), class = "factor"), city = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 6L), .Label = c("bb", "ccc", "ddd", "fff", 
"ggg", "hh"), class = "factor"), type = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("Type 1", "Type 2", "Type 4"), class = "factor"), 
value = 1:7), .Names = c("state", "city", "type", "value"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))
```

Dataframe `df1` looks like:

```
State City Type1 Type2
Aaa   bb    NA    NA
Dd    e    NA    NA
```

and dataframe `df2` looks like:

```
state city   type value
Aaa   bb Type 1     1
Aaa  ccc Type 2     2
Aaa  ddd Type 2     3
Dd  fff Type 2     4
Dd  fff Type 2     5
Dd  ggg Type 2     6
Dd   hh Type 4     7
```

For the `NA` in `df1`, I need to look up the values from `df2` according to the following rules:

1) If there is only a **single instance** where `State` = `state` and `City` = `city` for a given `type` in `df2`, insert `value` into the appropriate `df1` column `Type1` or `Type2`

2) When there are **multiple instances** where `State` = `state` and `City` = `city` for a given `type`, I need to average all `value` and insert this into `df1`

3) If there are **no instances** where `State` = `state` and `City` = `city` for a given `type`, I need to obtain the average of all `state` for this `type` and insert into `df1`

4) If there are **no instances** where `State` = `state` for a given `type`, then the value should remain `NA` in `df1`

**Just to clarify -- essentially I am trying to average values `Type1` and `Type2` as "resolved" as possible.  In other words, I want to use averages at the `City` level when possible, but when that is not possible, then I want to use `State` level averages.  However, I want to return these averages for the original `State` and `City` outlined in `df1` (even when `State` averages are all that is available**

I know that is very complicated!  The result I am trying to get is

```
structure(list(State = structure(1:2, .Label = c("Aaa", "Dd"), class = "factor"), 
City = structure(1:2, .Label = c("bb", "e"), class = "factor"), 
Type1 = c(1L, NA), Type2 = c(2.5, 5)), .Names = c("State", 
"City", "Type1", "Type2"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))
```

which is a dataframe like:

```
State City Type1 Type2
Aaa   bb     1   2.5
Dd    e    NA   5.0
```

I don't even know where to begin solving this.  My first thought is that I need to use `acast` to reshape `df2`.  For example, I can use

```
acast(df2, state+city+value~type)
```

which reshapes the data to more closely resemble `df1`, but then I loose some columns that I need to preserve (these get smooshed into the rowname).  I don't even know how to begin the challenge of searching for `City` and `State` and then doing the averaging depending on those results.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

**EDIT (Jan 2015):**  I added a new comment below Troy's answer below, asking if there was an easy way to add a column identifying the level at which means are calculated (City or State). I've found a solution and although there's likely a better way, it works for me. Hope this helps someone!

```
getlevel<-function(state,city,type){
m<-means[means$state==state & means$city==city & means$type==type, "mean"]
sm<-state_means[state_means$state==state & state_means$type==type, "mean"]
ifelse(length(m)>0,"city","state")
}
```

then

```
ddply(df1,.(State,City),transform,Type1=getval(as.character(State),as.character(City),"Type 1"),Type1Level=getlevel(as.character(State),as.character(City),"Type 1"),Type2=getval(as.character(State),as.character(City),"Type 2"),Type2Level=getlevel(as.character(State),as.character(City),"Type 2"))
```

Comment: notice that (1) is a special case of (2), so you can ignore (1) and just execute (2)

Comment: Great point Ricardo, I didn't even think of this!  =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT** - sorry misread the questions: here is the corrected code for your conditions:

```
require(plyr)
means<-ddply(df2,.(state,city,type),summarize,mean=mean(value))
state_means<-ddply(df2,.(state,type),summarize,mean=mean(value))
getval<-function(state,city,type){
  m<-means[means$state==state & means$city==city & means$type==type, "mean"]
  sm<-state_means[state_means$state==state & state_means$type==type, "mean"]
  ifelse(length(m)>0,m,sm)
}
## this gives you the new df1
ddply(df1,.(State,City),transform,Type1=getval(as.character(State),as.character(City),"Type 1"),Type2=getval(as.character(State),as.character(City),"Type 2"))
```

XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
PREVIOUS ANSWER (INCOMPLETE)

It's a bit difficult because your structure call doesn't work properly for df2, and your example datasets don't give you all the data in your expected result, but I think what you want is:

```
require(plyr)
means<-ddply(df2,.(state,city,type),summarize,mean=mean(value))
getval<-function(state,city,type){means[means$state==state & means$city==city & means$type==type, "mean"]}
## this gives you the new df1
ddply(df1,.(State,City),transform,Type1=getval(as.character(State),as.character(City),"Type 1"),Type2=getval(as.character(State),as.character(City),"Type 2"))

############################################################################X

## what's happening in detail:
require(plyr)                      # calls the plyr library
means<-ddply(df2,                  # base on df2 
             .(state,city,type),   # summarize by combination of city/state/type
             summarize,            # tells plyr to summarize rather than transform
             mean=mean(value))     # show one column at each summary level, called 'mean', the average val

getval<-function(state,city,type){     # create function called getval, takes 3 parameters
  means[means$state==state &           # first part of [X,]
          means$city==city &           # selects the row that matches all criteria
          means$type==type,            
        "mean"]}                       # and [,X] the column relating to the type

getval("Aaa","bb","Type 2")
# this gives you the new df2
ddply(df1,                             # base on df1
      .(State,City),                   # summarize by State & City
      transform,                       # tell plyr to transform existingn set rather than roll up
      Type1=getval(as.character(State),as.character(City),"Type 1"),   # call getval() for Type 1
      Type2=getval(as.character(State),as.character(City),"Type 2"))   # and for Type 2
```

which gives you the following (not your expected result, but what is implied by the data)

```
  State City Type1 Type2
1   Aaa   bb     1    NA
2    Dd    e    NA    NA
```

Comment: Dear Troy, thanks so much for your very informative answer.  It does the "1" answer, however for Type2 in the first row, the answer should be 2.5 (i.e. the mean of Type 2 for state Aaa = (2+3)/2 = 2.5).  Likewise, for Type2 in the bottom row, it should be the mean of all Type2 for state Dd = (4+5+6)/3 = 5.  Is there a way to include this averaging in your solution?

Comment: Sorry - my misreading of the conditions. It's corrected above

Comment: Dear Troy, I can't thank you enough for your help.  This makes sense and is a very elegant solution.  I wish I knew r better so I could immediately see solutions like this!  Now to try this on my massive dataset - thanks again!

Comment: Also, I overlooked the fact that one of my "type" values are strings like "corn" and "wheat" instead of numbers like used in my example.  I am sure this will throw some kind of error eventually.  I will have to think about how to deal with that... for each city, I will have only one string, but when working at the state level I may have some with "corn" and some with "wheat" and I can't take the mean of those obviously.  It might be best to just use the more common string that appears more times, but i'm not sure how to do that in the existing code.

Comment: Troy, when using this on my larger dataset, I get an error "In is.na(e1) | is.na(e2) :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
2: In `==.default`(state_means$state, state) :"  Any clue what might cause this?

Comment: Dear Troy, do you know if there would be a simple way to return a new column that identifies whether the city, state, or type level?  I.e., just a column reporting "city" for city-level means, "state" for state-level means, and so on?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First reshape the data in df2, then use `data.table`'s key to merge the data appropriately:

```
library(data.table)
library(reshape2)

dt1 <- as.data.table(df1)
dt2 <- as.data.table(df2)
```

#### First, fix the `Type` column of dt2 by reshaping

```
dt2.casted <- reshape2::dcast(dt2, state + city ~ type
                              , fill=NA_real_
                              , fun.aggregate=mean, na.rm=TRUE)
dt2.casted <- as.data.table(dt2.casted)
```

#### Next, set the `keys` so you can merge

```
setkey(dt2.casted, state, city)
setkey(dt1, State, City)
```

#### Finally, merge and take the mean, knocking out `NA`s

```
dt1[dt2.casted][, lapply(.SD, mean, na.rm=TRUE), by=State, .SDcols=grep("Type", names(dt2.casted), value=TRUE)]

   State Type 1 Type 2 Type 4
1:   Aaa      1   2.50    NaN
2:    Dd    NaN   5.25      7
```

---

#### Alternate, based on comments (no "city" aggregation)

```
dt2.casted <- reshape2::dcast(dt2, state ~ type
                              , fill=NA_real_
                              , fun.aggregate=mean, na.rm=TRUE)
dt2.casted <- as.data.table(dt2.casted)

setkey(dt2.casted, state)
setkey(dt1, State)

dt1[dt2.casted][, lapply(.SD, mean, na.rm=TRUE)
                , by=list(State, City)
                , .SDcols=grep("Type"
                , names(dt2.casted), value=TRUE)
                ]

   State City Type 1 Type 2 Type 4
1:   Aaa   bb      1    2.5    NaN
2:    Dd    e    NaN    5.0      7
```

Comment: Dear Ricardo, wow -- thanks so much for your help.  95% of your solution is completely new to me and I really appreciate the help!  This appears to be very close, however there does seem to be some issue with the averaging... Column Type 2 for State Dd should be 5, not 5.25 (i.e. since there is no city "e" for state "Dd", the solution should average all of the type2 for "Dd", so (4+5+6)/3 = 5.  Also, the solution table should have a column "City" next to state corresponding to the values in my original df1.  Is there some way to adjust your solution to accommodate these?

Comment: It looks like you just want to aggregate by State, not by city.  HAve a look at the edit

Comment: Dear Ricardo, thanks again very much for your help!  Somehow I still do want to aggregate by city. I think I was unclear in exactly what I'm trying to do.  I edited my comments yesterday to try and clarify, i'm not sure if you saw those or not.  It seems like your solution is giving the correct means, however I do need a "city" column in the final result.  Also, if a city-level mean is available I want to use that, if not then use instead the state-level mean.  Cheers!

Comment: @thomas, if you need a city column, just add it to the `by=` argument.  see above

Comment: Thanks Ricardo, much appreciated.  I am curious to see how this solution compares to Troy's solution in terms of calculation speed.  My real data have 136,000 rows!